# Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, substring

I have the following T-SQL query which works fine:

```
declare @myString varchar(max) = 'Import Development \ local \ Jan
2016 \ Jenny Asti \ reimbur.docx'  

select substring((@myString), 1, len(@myString) - charindex('\', reverse (@myString)))
```

I am looking to return the string before the last backslash and and I am correctly getting this:

`Testing Development \ local \ Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti`

However, I need to run this command for a table and not using a variable. So, I've changed to the following:

```
select substring([path], 1, len(path)- charindex('\',reverse(path))) from test
```

But I get an error: `Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.`

I can confirm that the `\` does exist in the table. Also, if I look at the results windows, the query is able to list this:

> Import Development \ local \ Jan 2016 \ Jenny

I believe there is something wrong parsing the last part of the string 
`Asti \ reimbur.docx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you are using will return incorrect result if the source value has trailing spaces.

For example:

```
declare @myString varchar(max) = 'Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti \ reimbur.docx';
select substring((@myString), 1, len(@myString) - charindex('\', reverse (@myString)))
```

returns:

```
Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti
```

But,

```
declare @myString varchar(max) = 'Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti \ reimbur.docx    ';
select substring((@myString), 1, len(@myString) - charindex('\', reverse (@myString)))
```

returns:

```
Jan 2016 \ Jenny A
```

I have added four spaces in the second example.

The reason for this behaviour is that `LEN` function returns the length of the string ignoring the trailing spaces, but `REVERSE` doesn't ignore them.

One way to fix the formula is to trim the trailing spaces:

```
declare @myString varchar(max) = 'Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti \ reimbur.docx    ';
select substring((@myString), 1, len(@myString) - charindex('\', reverse(RTRIM(@myString))))
```

this will return correct result:

```
Jan 2016 \ Jenny Asti
```

---

You are getting that error message

> Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.

because `LEN` of original string and `LEN` of reversed string are different due to trailing spaces in your data.

For example (note, that there are two trailing spaces in the string):

```
declare @myString varchar(max) = 'a\b  ';
select substring((@myString), 1, len(@myString) - charindex('\', reverse (@myString)))
```

will return:

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Comment: Vladimir, you rock!!! That solved my issue, many thanks and I do appreciated your help.